# Flyway hanging after few migrations on AWS RDS Mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, flyway

I can't seem to figure this one out... Up until now we are using Flyway with Percona XtraDB Cluster 5.6 on AWS, but since RDS is giving better performance and can be configured to be highly available we want to switch (there is no mysql compentence on our team).

One would think once the RDS is up and running, one should be able to simply point flyway to the new server and set it up... One would be wrong!

After 5 migration scripts flyway stops... Trying to query the DB isn't really working, so assuming some kind of locking which has gone wrong.

Flyway -X tells me this:

> Migrating schema `common` to version 1.1
>
> DEBUG: Found statement at line 1: ALTER TABLE use...
>
> DEBUG: Found statement at line 2: ALTER TABLE use...
>
> DEBUG: Executing SQL: ALTER TABLE use...
>
> DEBUG: Executing SQL: ALTER TABLE use...
>
> DEBUG: Successfully completed and committed migration of schema `common` to version 1.1
>
> DEBUG: MetaData table `common`.`schema_version` successfully updated to reflect changes
>
> DEBUG: Locking table `common`.`schema_version`...
>
> DEBUG: Lock acquired for table `common`.`schema_version`
>
> Migrating schema `common` to version 1.2
>
> DEBUG: Found statement at line 1: ALTER TABLE use...
>
> DEBUG: Executing SQL: ALTER TABLE use...)
>
> DEBUG: Successfully completed and committed migration of schema `common` to version 1.2
>
> DEBUG: MetaData table `common`.`schema_version` successfully updated to reflect changes
>
> DEBUG: Locking table `common`.`schema_version`...
>
> DEBUG: Lock acquired for table `common`.`schema_version`
>
> Migrating schema `common` to version 1.3
>
> DEBUG: Found statement at line 2: CREATE TABLE rou...
>
> DEBUG: Executing SQL: CREATE TABLE rou...
>
> DEBUG: Successfully completed and committed migration of schema `common` to version 1.3
>
> DEBUG: MetaData table `common`.`schema_version` successfully updated to reflect changes
>
> DEBUG: Locking table `common`.`schema_version`...
>
> DEBUG: Lock acquired for table `common`.`schema_version`
>
> Migrating schema `common` to version 1.4
>
> DEBUG: Found statement at line 1: ALTER TABLE use...
>
> DEBUG: Executing SQL: ALTER TABLE use...
>
> DEBUG: Successfully completed and committed migration of schema `common` to version 1.4
>
> DEBUG: MetaData table `common`.`schema_version` successfully updated to reflect changes
>
> DEBUG: Locking table `common`.`schema_version`...
>
> (hangs forever from here)

There are lots of scripts remaining (10+) that aren't executed. Killing flyway and restarting it will make it hang on connecting to the DB. The only way to fix this is to delete the schema, recreate the schema and then retry the flyway migrate. It will always hang at the exact same spot. it's also not something in the script, as I tried replacing the fourth and fifth script with another.
When the SQL commands are run from MySQL Workbench they simply work, on both Percona and RDS.

Answer (score 0):

Was an AWS RDS issue, not a Flyway one: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/772